# Blinking a div with background-color in jquery using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

the code :

```
<div id="divtoBlink" ></div>
```

css:

```
#divtoBlink{
 width:100px;
 height:20px;
 background-color:#627BAE;
}
```

javascript:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $("#divtoBlink").css("background-color","red");
  },100)
```

but nothing is happening can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong ?

fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/F7hBz/)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I suggest you don't change the color with javascript. It's better practice to do this via CSS. Changing styles should be done in a *style*sheet, not in JS (in case if you want other/more properties changed).

You toggle a class, that class has a background definition (in this example, if you want you can add more properties). A [fiddle as DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LkuNB/1/)

```
<div id="divtoBlink" ></div>

.blinker{
    background: red;
}

let $div2blink = $("#divtoBlink"); // Save reference for better performance
let backgroundInterval = setInterval(function(){
    $div2blink.toggleClass("blinker");
 },100)
```

---

If you feel like a wild mood, you can add some css3 animation to it

```
#div2blink{
    transition: backgroundColor 0.05s ease-in-out;
}
```

Made a demo for the animation: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LkuNB/1855/) (I slowed it down in the example!)

Comment: please provide full code for an animation (`keyframes` etc) if you are speaking of one

Comment: Keyframes are not needed in this case. Ill make a example for you

Comment: then use `transition` as `css animation` refers to an other technique

Comment: but how can i stop the toggle functionality ? i would just remove the class ?

Comment: @Vp: I've added a demo for the animation. @Sora: You use `clearInterval()`, I've added it to my code how you save it, you figure out how to clear it ;)

Comment: @PawełStasicki: I suggest this version: http://jsfiddle.net/LkuNB/2557/

Answer (score 7):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q9GMz/2/)

```
setInterval(function () {
    $("#divtoBlink").css("background-color", function () {
        this.switch = !this.switch
        return this.switch ? "red" : ""
    });
}, 100)
```

Comment: This will blink between two defined colors which might not be optimal. You should (ideally) not use JS to control colors, thats what css is for :)

Comment: `this.switch` might be unobvious to beginners, one can use a global (or from parent closure) variable for switching

Comment: I like the this.switch, as powerfull as it is simple

Comment: @Martijn i'm just answering question, not optimizing any code which anyway and don't know exact expectation

Comment: @Vprimachenko oops, forget 'this' is refering window, my bad

Comment: You can change the hex value to `""`, it will make it toggle instead of a fixed color

Comment: @Martijn clever move!

Comment: This is perfect for what I needed. The accepted answer can only be applied to an element with an ID. This answer can be applied to any element matching a class (which means I can have many blinking cells in a table) thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```css
.blink-div {
    background: green;
    animation: flash 2s ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="blink-div">
  Hello World
</div>
```

Another way to animate a div is by using the css3 animations.

```
.blink-div {
   animation: flash 2s ease infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another example, but with much color and speed (based on martijn's example). Seizure warning:

```
var $div2blink = $("#divtoBlink"); // Save reference, only look this item up once, then save
var color = 0
var color_classes = ["backgroundRed", "backgroundYellow", "backgroundBlue"];
var backgroundInterval = setInterval(function(){
        color++;
    if (color === 3){
        color = 0;
    }
    $div2blink.toggleClass(color_classes[color]);
 },10)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LkuNB/1983/

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it with pure CSS:

```
#divtoBlink{
    -webkit-animation: bgblink 3s;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
@-webkit-keyframes bgblink {
    from {background-color: #fff;}
    50% {color:#000}
    to {background-color: #fff;}
}
@keyframes bgblink {
    from {background-color: #fff;}
    50% {background-color:#000}
    to {background-color: #fff;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at below code

HTML:

```
<div id="divtoBlink" ></div>
```

CSS:

```
#divtoBlink{
 width:100px;
 height:20px;
background-color:#627BAE;
}

.class2{
     background-color:#ff0000 !important;
}
```

JS :

```
setInterval(function(){
  $("#divtoBlink").toggleClass("class2");
  },100)
```

Comment: Though this will work, class1 isnt needed at all. Just add that code to `#divtoBlink`. Will save code and improve readability

Comment: Changed as per your comments but need to mark `!important' for class value so that it will override the ID value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to change the color one time to "red", change background-color to backgroundColor

```
setInterval(function(){
$("#divtoBlink").css("backgroundColor","red");
},100)
```

If you want to toggle the class, than you have to do it with .toggle

Comment: This will set the backgroundcolor to red, every 100ms. Nothing will toggle or change, only after the first illiteration (setting it red)

Comment: This is what I said, if you want to toggle it you had to put the "toggle" in. I also said that the example above only change it one time!

Comment: If you know it only does it once, why an interval? That makes no sense at all :P