# How to change 'div' background and text colour using jquery to flash a message And revert back to original colors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` with id and class names as `tab`. The `css` are defined for the `div`. The original `background-color` is blue and `color` is white. I need to flash some text on this `div` , where the message should flash 3 times with black background and white text and vice versa.

I tried `toggleClass`. Using this the effect is generated but the previous class css is not restored.

I have tried fade also `$("#tab").fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);` , it helps the blinking part but doesnt give the desired results.

Please suggest... Thanks in advance.

This is what i have tried so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

<style type="text/css">
.backgroundRed
{
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: red;
}
.blink
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var flg = 0;

$.fn.blink = function()
{ 
    var i = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            { 
                // attempt#1 // 
                //blinking works well with this ////
                //$("#test").fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);

                // attempt#2 // 
                //changes looks good but doesnt revert back to original class ////
                //$(".backgroundRed").toggleClass("blink");
                //$("#test").removeClass("blink");
                //$("#test").addClass("backgroundRed");

                // attempt #3 //
                // doesnt work correctly        
            if(i >= 3) 
                {
                    $("#test").fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
                    $("#test").removeClass("blink");
                    $("#test").addClass("backgroundRed");
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#test").fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
                    $("#test").removeClass("backgroundRed");
                    $("#test").addClass("blink");
                }
            }



}

$("#tab").click(function(){

    $.fn.blink();

});


});




</script>

<html>
<body>

<div id="test" class="backgroundRed" style="height: 200px; width: 400px; ">

<h1>test value</h1>

</div>

<button id="tab">click</button>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you show us what code you have so far?

Comment: toggleClass() to add your specific class. fadeIn() and fadeOut() for the blinking part.

Comment: You can use this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19049560/3008050)

Comment: I have pasted the code that i have tried , please take a look.

Comment: @karan3112 i tried that one, but i am unable to stop that effect and go back to the original class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sydzL8Lc/21/

Using https://github.com/madbook/jquery.wait and since you want blink 3 times

```
$("#test").addClass("blink").wait(400).removeClass("blink").wait(400).addClass("blink").wait(400).removeClass("blink");
```

Comment: Added the jquery.wait.js file and tested, couldnt see any effects... am i missing something??

Comment: Not sure what to recommend, since the fiddle works. Compare your code to fiddle, see if there's any difference. Misspelt the class name or you need to use another selector?

Comment: The fiddle is not working for me... its just plain black background and white text... flashing part doesnt work... that is what i got on the fiddle. Are u able to see the effects??

Comment: Flashing works for me on fiddle. Have you tried another browser? I'm using firefox.

Comment: This worked...!!! Had some issue with the browser i guess... Thanks a lot... pretty much what was needed ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this blink()

```
     function blink(){    
        var i = 0;
        var obj = setInterval(function(){
            if(i == 5)
            {
                $("#divtoBlink").removeClass("backgroundRed");
                clearInterval(obj);
            }else{
                $("#divtoBlink").toggleClass("backgroundRed");
            }
            i++;
         },100)
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LkuNB/593/)